# dev/loop0 shows 99 % full - Cannot Download files

Tags: partitioning, mount

dev/loop0 shows 99 % full. When i run df -h it shows the following :

Filesystem  Size   Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/loop0  17G    17G  267M  99%  /

I try to download some files but it gives me a disk full error. Can someone please guide me on how to free up the dev/loop0 space?

Comment: Other option would be to expand your virtual disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out where the /dev/loop0 device is mounted on the filesystem. Use 
    mount

and then look for the line that's 
/dev/loop0 on

You can find out what's using the space using 
    du  | sort -nr  | more

which will tell you how much space each file is using. Then choose which one to delete.

However, this will be a lot of text to trawl through. A more graphical option (that I prefer) is GdMap - http://gdmap.sourceforge.net